# Magento 1.9: Massive set customer confirmation attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, database, customer, import, confirmation

I imported over 3000 customers in magento, I need to set them all as confirmed. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you just have to remove the value of the attribute `confirmation` for each of this customer. If a customer has a `confirmation` attribute value set that means that confirmation is required. Without that value a customer is considered confirmed.

You can do that either with the following code for a given `$id` (for example you can loop through all ids if you now them):

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
$customer->setConfirmation(null);
$customer->save();
```

or by running a SQL statement

```
delete from customer_entity_varchar 
where attribute_id = ( 
       select attribute_id from eav_attribute 
         where entity_type_id = 1 and attribute_code = 'confirmation'
)
and entity_id = [YOUR CUSTOMER ID TO CONFIRM];
```

If you now the ids of the customer you can specify the range in SQL and delete all (I assume all imported ids are coherently):

```
delete from customer_entity_varchar 
where attribute_id = ( 
    select attribute_id from eav_attribute 
       where entity_type_id = 1 and attribute_code = 'confirmation'
)
and entity_id >= [YOUR SMALLEST CUSTOMER ID TO CONFIRM]
and entity_id <= [YOUR LARGEST CUSTOMER ID TO CONFIRM];
```